# CMD to open VLC player with folder

Tags: cmd

I try to open a folder with vlc player per a cmd file.
this is what I have:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC" vlc.exe D:\Micha\Music\platten\platten\dance
Exit
```

but it dont work... please help a cmd newbe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have it.. Sorry
@echo on
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" D:\Micha\Music\platten\platten\dance\
Exit